# An empty DataTable with column names from SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I am developing a project in SharePoint 2010.

My requirement is to get an empty DataTable but with column names in it from SharePoint List.

The .GetDataTable() method returns only if it has a value.

So basically I need a structure of the list in a DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an empty datatable if the GetDataTable does not retrieve column information.

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

foreach (SPField spf in _lst.Fields)
{
   _dt.Columns.Add(spf.InternalName.ToString(), spf.Type.GetType());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emmie! It worked great.
One question if I do not opt for 'spf.Type.GetType()' then what will be the default datatype for my DataTable ? 

like : _dt.Columns.Add(spf.InternalName.ToString());

Comment: I would always add a type.  You can try it without and see if it works.  I believe the default maybe string but I am not sure.